# Dependency Changes For Oreo Gives Error

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After changing **build.gradle** dependency to

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#custom-tabs), the project builds successfully but when I try to run it gives errors like

> error: cannot find symbol variable super
>
> error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>
> error: cannot find symbol method finish()
>
> error: cannot find symbol method getResources()
>
> error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
  }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about updating the other two support libraries `support-v4` and `cardview-v7` to `26.1.0` and performing a clean build?

Comment: Also Change this Two Library compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0' and compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' but error remain same.

Comment: did you `clean`?

Comment: yes,I Do Clean and also Invalidate and restart android studio.

Comment: can you post the class that these errors appear in? Since the errors appear when running, please also post the logcat

Comment: try to use http instead https for maven url.

Comment: @Pleft I have Too many Classes that gives different kind of error, I Explained My Error in Questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue resolve after Changes my Dependances.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

And Build Versions are Like below.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

The Issue was becase of ActionbarActivity. I have Some Activities that extens ActionbarActivity.
so Just Replaced Actionbaractivity to Appcompact Activity.

Note that:
android developers documentation says : "Updated the AppCompatActivity as the base class for activities that use the support library action bar features. This class replaces the deprecated ActionBarActivity."

Answer (score 0):

Create new class in your `java` folder of your module:
 Package structure:

java /
android / support / v7 / app /

```
package android.support.v7.app;

public class ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

Add following in project-level build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true

}
```

inside dependencies:

```
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```